# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/..."):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello Im creating an app that has user profiles.

When i click on a user such as http://localhost:3000/users/53 i receive this error.

I tried looking around but can't really find an answer. Anyone have any ideas?

```
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/..."):
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
      web-console (2.1.2) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
      railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
      railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
      activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
      railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
      actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
      rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
      rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
```

Here is some of my user_controller.rb **pay attention to def show**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
    @item = @user.items.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  get 'sessions/new'

  resources :users
  root 'items#index'
  get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get 'show'  => 'users#show'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :items
  get 'items' => 'items#index'
  get 'items_new' => 'items#new'
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3">
        <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:large) %> 
    </div>  
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1><%= @user.username %> </h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-contact btn-md"> Contact Seller <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-verifiedsafsy btn-md"> Verified Safsy Retailer </button>
      <% if logged_in? %>
        <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_path(current_user) %>
      <% end %>
      <p><%= @user.description %> </p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-usershow">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">On Sale</a></li>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Policies<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Warranty Policies</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Money Back Policies</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Manage Policies<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Edit Money Back Policies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Edit Warranty Policies</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Manage Items<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Edit Items", edit_item_path %></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Upload Item Images</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        <% end %>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- /.Items Start -->

<div id="items" class="transitions-enabled">
    <% @item.each do |item| %>
        <div class="box panel panel-default">
          <div class="itemlisttitle"><%= item.title %></div>    
        <%= link_to image_tag(item.image.url (:medium)), item %>
          <div class ="panel-body">
        <div class = "itemlistprice">$<%= item.price %></div>
          <div class = "itemlistretailer"><%= image_tag item.user.avatar(:thumb) %> Retailer:  <%= link_to item.user.username, item.user %></button></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to user.username, user %>
      <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
        | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                    data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
        <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

Rake Routes

```
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
    password_resets_new GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
   password_resets_edit GET    /password_resets/edit(.:format)         password_resets#edit
           sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                 sessions#new
                  users GET    /users(.:format)                        users#index
                        POST   /users(.:format)                        users#create
               new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                    users#new
              edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
                   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                        PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
                   root GET    /                                       items#index
                 signup GET    /signup(.:format)                       users#new
                   show GET    /show(.:format)                         users#show
                  login GET    /login(.:format)                        sessions#new
                        POST   /login(.:format)                        sessions#create
                 logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                       sessions#destroy
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format) account_activations#edit
        password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)              password_resets#create
     new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)          password_resets#new
    edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)     password_resets#edit
         password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
                        PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)          password_resets#update
                  items GET    /items(.:format)                        items#index
                        POST   /items(.:format)                        items#create
               new_item GET    /items/new(.:format)                    items#new
              edit_item GET    /items/:id/edit(.:format)               items#edit
                   item GET    /items/:id(.:format)                    items#show
                        PATCH  /items/:id(.:format)                    items#update
                        PUT    /items/:id(.:format)                    items#update
                        DELETE /items/:id(.:format)                    items#destroy
                        GET    /items(.:format)                        items#index
              items_new GET    /items_new(.:format)                    items#new
```

Terminal when <%= link_to user.username, user_url(user.id) %>

```
Started GET "/users/53" for ::1 at 2015-06-22 20:22:15 +1000
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"53"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 53]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 53]]
  Item Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0  [["user_id", 53]]
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (15.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 235ms (Views: 232.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/users/..." for ::1 at 2015-06-22 20:22:15 +1000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/..."):
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
```

curl http://localhost:3000/users/53 -I

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Etag: W/"d70c0ea37c6a75c8aea771f5e96bd055"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: e3d7ff1e-bd51-4cbf-bdac-6b4c6c75172e
X-Runtime: 0.264128
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.0/2014-12-25)
Date: Mon, 22 Jun 2015 11:12:55 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: request_method=HEAD; path=/
Set-Cookie: _Safsy_session=bm5ZbGJLZmIwWUl3ZjZUNGdRdHBDNVo0QytpeFBRdGxJTVc3TW10L1Y1Uzh2K2ZGbS84OXgzcERpRmpLTS9Dcm1oOEZOUkZSVzBVSCtyK3JLenFmSzh1d2hVTnRVSm9PTWJ5VjBxb2VxcWZXOTkvYjBYelUxVFQvbjJMckNYSnNjR0xwNnVnQ05xV0dQM09NSVBjMnl3PT0tLU5yNXd2MnorOUI4UjUrUTNXcEd6SHc9PQ%3D%3D--18b34530b0b6057a407cf5c75e9030a65dc40b78; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

curl http://localhost:3000/users/53

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/account_activations.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/custom.self-67f4985d650835863f6b97d60548fab2cc8c7676d63d64638bf1fd8dd3bf7d4c.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/items.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/password_resets.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/sessions.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/static_pages.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/test.self-c992de9a95b561d539410291a094116c8e80b92a8c80f3bcf66ce5931d4786db.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-167193cd81d9330d9ddb5c4ec7b44214fea529aa8a94f3a86e6526e4f652fc02.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/masonry/transitions.self-a7dd920491429cc09dda36f003350cf98f5cec3c45d00888fab83293dce6ce92.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/font-awesome.self-2d17540bab3759939e910ca38a695f014e0c777ded3ad7a01c4658b9d3fc980d.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-8e98a7a072a6cee1372d19fff9ff3e6aa1e39a37d89d6f06861637d061113ee7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-2bbd2c0465f01b1f8270958ddfc2e62a08915f295a35d22df2971eb936cf3c64.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.turbolinks.self-176b9819f30444d441e820bbccd3264fe57753aeafd54dec732b0dbc77129a2a.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/masonry/jquery.masonry.self-e55a2ca40f0bd20129930439c10a6b8c5dd26787b41fd8427db5b9da8c2af52f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/masonry/jquery.infinitescroll.min.self-256ba3b85df8047d77b78d954ad6cab2df8fb3d476787b18fa8663ae7753e517.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/masonry/jquery.imagesloaded.min.self-c1d43d59c51c96f38689232f330c6de2816ec55a026ab1276dde2fbdf94b03d7.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/account_activations.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/items.self-46f32c832de7915a15f17579ee8a6ff79f7b9c924034a18e363cb427ad404b3f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/password_resets.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/sessions.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/static_pages.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-7e0339a5d0f7fe1d2ad7452cb924235cd3fb860666cf3881132946c74a5acf7c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="h5xZUgBSAnDnH8jQpCF/R3QNH/eott0gxlkhc0AoLA/QuuEANMBeJsSRtKoFP95raIt/3eAs0ajcu6bHBcsiyg==" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:500,900,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
      </script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Safsy" src="...">
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" >Shop <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
      </form>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">   
            <li><a href="/login">Log In</a></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="/system/users/avatars/000/000/053/large/23.mobile-phone-logos.png?1434455583" alt="23.mobile phone logos" /> 
    </div>  
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <section class="user_info">
      <h1>drknoba </h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-contact btn-md"> Contact Seller <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-verifiedsafsy btn-md"> Verified Safsy Retailer </button>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec suscipit augue id leo pharetra condimentum. Phasellus et elit ac nisl finibus elementum et efficitur lorem. Sed nec lacinia mi. Sed massa tortor, iaculis eget diam ac, luctus ultricies ipsum. Quisque posuere sollicitudin congue. Suspendisse sapien ligula, tempus at pulvinar a, mattis nec lacus.  </p>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-usershow">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Items</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">On Sale</a></li>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Policies<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Warranty Policies</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Money Back Policies</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- /.Items Start -->

<div id="items" class="transitions-enabled">
        <div class="box panel panel-default">
          <div class="itemlisttitle">Apple iPad Air 16gb Black</div>    
        <a href="/items/11"><img src="/system/items/images/000/000/011/medium/Apple_iPad_Air_2_4G_16_Black.jpg?1434022086" alt="Apple ipad air 2 4g 16 black" /></a>
          <div class ="panel-body">
        <div class = "itemlistprice">$590.0</div>
          <div class = "itemlistretailer"><img src="/system/users/avatars/000/000/053/thumb/23.mobile-phone-logos.png?1434455583" alt="23.mobile phone logos" /> Retailer:  <a href="/users/53">drknoba</a></button></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box panel panel-default">
          <div class="itemlisttitle">Apple iPad Air 16gb White</div>    
        <a href="/items/12"><img src="/system/items/images/000/000/012/medium/Apple_iPad_Air_2_4G_16_White.jpg?1434022127" alt="Apple ipad air 2 4g 16 white" /></a>
          <div class ="panel-body">
        <div class = "itemlistprice">$580.0</div>
          <div class = "itemlistretailer"><img src="/system/users/avatars/000/000/053/thumb/23.mobile-phone-logos.png?1434455583" alt="23.mobile phone logos" /> Retailer:  <a href="/users/53">drknoba</a></button></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box panel panel-default">
          <div class="itemlisttitle">HTC 901</div>  
        <a href="/items/13"><img src="/system/items/images/000/000/013/medium/HTC_901s_BUTTERFLY_S_Pink.jpg?1434022153" alt="Htc 901s butterfly s pink" /></a>
          <div class ="panel-body">
        <div class = "itemlistprice">$499.0</div>
          <div class = "itemlistretailer"><img src="/system/users/avatars/000/000/053/thumb/23.mobile-phone-logos.png?1434455583" alt="23.mobile phone logos" /> Retailer:  <a href="/users/53">drknoba</a></button></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box panel panel-default">
          <div class="itemlisttitle">Nokia Lumia 830 Black</div>    
        <a href="/items/14"><img src="/system/items/images/000/000/014/medium/Nokia_Lumia_830_Black.jpg?1434022181" alt="Nokia lumia 830 black" /></a>
          <div class ="panel-body">
        <div class = "itemlistprice">$699.0</div>
          <div class = "itemlistretailer"><img src="/system/users/avatars/000/000/053/thumb/23.mobile-phone-logos.png?1434455583" alt="23.mobile phone logos" /> Retailer:  <a href="/users/53">drknoba</a></button></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box panel panel-default">
          <div class="itemlisttitle">Samsung Galaxy S5 G800 45 Blue</div>   
        <a href="/items/15"><img src="/system/items/images/000/000/015/medium/Samsung_G800f_Galaxy_S5_Mini_4G_Blue.jpeg?1434022213" alt="Samsung g800f galaxy s5 mini 4g blue" /></a>
          <div class ="panel-body">
        <div class = "itemlistprice">$699.0</div>
          <div class = "itemlistretailer"><img src="/system/users/avatars/000/000/053/thumb/23.mobile-phone-logos.png?1434455583" alt="23.mobile phone logos" /> Retailer:  <a href="/users/53">drknoba</a></button></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box panel panel-default">
          <div class="itemlisttitle">Apple iPhone 5 16gb Yellow</div>   
        <a href="/items/16"><img src="/system/items/images/000/000/016/medium/Apple_iPhone5C_8GB_Yellow.jpg?1434022252" alt="Apple iphone5c 8gb yellow" /></a>
          <div class ="panel-body">
        <div class = "itemlistprice">$449.0</div>
          <div class = "itemlistretailer"><img src="/system/users/avatars/000/000/053/thumb/23.mobile-phone-logos.png?1434455583" alt="23.mobile phone logos" /> Retailer:  <a href="/users/53">drknoba</a></button></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box panel panel-default">
          <div class="itemlisttitle">Asus Zenfone CG 8gb Red</div>  
        <a href="/items/17"><img src="/system/items/images/000/000/017/medium/Asus_Zenfone_5_A501CG_8gb_R.jpg?1434102110" alt="Asus zenfone 5 a501cg 8gb r" /></a>
          <div class ="panel-body">
        <div class = "itemlistprice">$400.0</div>
          <div class = "itemlistretailer"><img src="/system/users/avatars/000/000/053/thumb/23.mobile-phone-logos.png?1434455583" alt="23.mobile phone logos" /> Retailer:  <a href="/users/53">drknoba</a></button></div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <h3> Support </h3>
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-2  col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <h3> Shop </h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"> Feature Items </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Mobile Phones </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Headphones </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Cameras </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Laptop Computers </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Tablet Computers </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both" class="hide visible-xs"></div>

                <div class="col-lg-2  col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <h3> Information </h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"> About Us </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Buyer Protection Policy </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Terms & Conditions </a></li>
                        <li><a href="signup"> Become A Seller </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-2  col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                    <h3> My Account </h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"> Account Login </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> My Account </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Wish List </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Orders </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Messages </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div style="clear:both" class="hide visible-xs"></div>

                <div class="col-lg-3  col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
                    <h3> Social </h3>
                    <ul class="social">
                        <li><a href="http://facebook.com"> <i class=" fa fa-facebook"> &nbsp; </i> </a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://twitter.com"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"> &nbsp; </i> </a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus"> &nbsp; </i> </a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://youtube.com"> <i class="fa fa-pinterest"> &nbsp; </i> </a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://youtube.com"> <i class="fa fa-youtube"> &nbsp; </i> </a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--/.row-->
        </div>
        <!--/.container-->

    <!--/.footer-->
    <div class="footer-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="pull-left">
                &copy; 2015 Safsy Enterprises PTY LTD - All rights reserved.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.footer-bottom-->
</footer>

  </body>

</html>

Josephs-Mac-Pro:Safsy josephkonop$
```

Comment: Are you sure that the href on those links is correct? Have you looked at the html source? Do you get the same error if you enter `http://localhost:3000/users/53` in the address bar?

Comment: Please post your `show.html.erb`

Comment: Can you restart server well?

Comment: Sorry i meant to ask `index.html.erb` not show.

Comment: @ppascualv. I dont understand? Even if i restart server the same happens.

Comment: @Pavan I just added it.

Comment: `index.html.erb` please

Comment: @Pavan i just added intex.html.erb.

Comment: @maxcal yes when i type that into the address bar it comes up with the same error.

Comment: Thats really strange, I can't see why rails would alter the request url. I have never seen this bug before. Some wild theories: Maybe you have some kind of proxy which takes the request and mangles it before it is passed to Rails. Maybe it could be a rogue rack component which messes up the request before it is passed to rails?

Comment: run `rake routes` and put here the output please

Comment: @ppascualv I have added rake routes. Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `<%= link_to user.username, user_url(user.id) %>` in index.html

Comment: @ppascualv same thing. I just added to the post what the terminal says. Take a look. Its so weird.

Comment: Your show action looks fine. Something is redirecting it after rendering the page. What's in your `before_action` hooks? Also, javascript?

Comment: @fylooi - the ActionController::RoutingError is raised before the request is even passed to a controller. In fact its because rails kind find a route to tell it which controller to pass the request to. Since he also tested writing the url in the address bar you can rule out js or in that the link is wrong.

Comment: You could check for a redirect with `curl http://localhost:3000/users/53 -I`

Comment: @maxcal: `show` seems to render fine in the terminal log he posted.

Comment: Your're absolutely right @fylooi, my bad. Must be somewhere in the view or a helper.

Comment: @fylooi when you say javascript. I hope you mean application.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require masonry/jquery.infinitescroll.min
//= require masonry/jquery.imagesloaded.min
//= require_tree .

Comment: @maxcal i have posted what happens when i do curl http://localhost:3000/users/53 -I

Comment: @joeyk16: not application.js, any javascript in your views which do a redirect? Eg. `window.location = '...'`. Also, are there any `before_actions` / `after_actions` in your `ApplicationController`?

Comment: Do you get an error page if you do `curl http://localhost:3000/users/53` without the -I option.

Comment: @maxcal I added what happens in terminal when i enter curl http://localhost:3000/users/53 i didnt see any errors

Comment: @fylooi i have added my applications controller.

Comment: Thanks for all you're help so far guys.

Comment: NP. `<img alt="Safsy" src="...">` could be the culprit.

Comment: @joeyk16: The million dollar question - does `show` render as intended in the browser?

Comment: @maxcal that fixed it. ERMEHGERD. That was a mission. I can't believe it. Thanks so much guys what a great help that was. I spent probably 5 hours on it myself. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: No problem. That was an interesting one - the reason it errored in the browser and not in cURL is that cURL does not actually parse the HTML and request images and scripts and things...